# How to get the http method used in curl_php()

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, php-curl

How to get the HTTP method(like GET,POST,DELETE) used in the curl_php connections? It is not avaiable in `curl_getinfo`.
The code for the connection is

```
$options = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
    );
    $response = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($response, $options);
    $content  = curl_exec($response);
    $options_debug = curl_getinfo($response);
    curl_close($response);
```

Comment: There's no way to do it afaik. But since you have to configure it explicitly, you can write a wrapper that keeps track of it.

Answer (score 0):

By default cURL methods are always GET unless you specify it differently. Also, if you invoke cURL with -d or --data the request will be POST.

```
POST request override default GET when using -d parameter.
```

More info here: [cURL info](https://zaiste.net/introduction_to_curl/)

BR